# Error when compiling with zlib 1.2.8 on windows

Tags: windows, debugging, visual-studio-2012, zlib, icc

I'm linking against zlib 1.2.8 in my application built with VS2012 and ICC 13.0. When I compile a file where < zlib.h > is included **before** < windows.h >, there is no problem. When < zlib.h > is included **after** < windows.h >, I got an error in < zconf.h >, line 454 where the compiler tries to include < unistd.h >. Worst than that, I put a *#pragma message()* just before this #include and the message doesn't appear in the build output window!

I tried the famous **WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN** but it changed nothing.

Does someone have an idea about the solution for this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: You already have the solution.  Put the zlib.h before.

Comment: Hi Mark! Of course this can be a solution but #include's should not have to be sorted this way, no? There must be a conflict somewhere and I would like to know what it is. If I must include zlib.h before, I have to change **a lot** of code.

Comment: Ah, ok.  When you said there is no problem, I thought you meant that there is no problem.

Answer (score 2):

OK, this bug is closed.

The problem came from another third-party library where the macro **HAVE_UNISTD_H** was erroneously defined. This defined had no impact on that library but forbid to compile with zlib.

My correction was to add a

```
#undef HAVE_UNISTD_H
```

in zlib.h or in the other library .h file(s).

Comment: Or you could put it in your source code between the include's.  It's probably best to not modify provided header files, since you then have to remember to modify them again if you get a new version.